# Problem when amqp channel is connected to spring integration http inbound-gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I try to connect spring integration amqp channels on a int-http:inbound-gateway component.
As i'm new in with springIntegration i started integration samples, especially with the one:
explaining how to setup a basic amqp channel.
I tried to write a simple message on my browser with the following code

```
    <int:channel id="toRabbit" />
    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="toRabbit" amqp-template="amqpTemplate" exchange-name="si.test.exchange"
                                       routing-key="si.test.binding" />

    <!-- From RabbitMQ To http gateway -->
    <int:channel id="fromRabbit" />
    <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="fromRabbit"
                                      queue-names="si.test.queue" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <int-http:inbound-gateway id="gateway"
                              request-channel="toRabbit"
                              reply-channel="response"
                              path="/hello"
                              supported-methods="GET">
        <int-http:request-mapping consumes="!text/xml,text/*,application/xml" produces="application/json" />
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>

    <int:channel id="response" />
    <int:service-activator input-channel="fromRabbit" output-channel="response">
        <bean class="com.example.demo.MyService"/>
    </int:service-activator>

    <!-- Infrastructure -->
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" />
    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
    <rabbit:queue name="si.test.queue" />
    <rabbit:direct-exchange name="si.test.exchange">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="si.test.queue" key="si.test.binding" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>
</beans>
```

With MyService containing:

```
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

public class MyService {
    public Message<String> processRequest(Message<String> message) {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello world").copyHeaders(message.getHeaders()).build();
    }
}
```

And the AmqpHttpApplication:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class AmqpHttpApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I was expecting that the result of MyService will be sent to the inbound-gateway reply-channel, but at runtime i get the following message:

Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available

If i use a pure Spring integration channel, every thing goes fine because the replyChannel is preserved.